# magento running even after deleting core modules files

Tags: magento-1.9, cache

I have developed magento theme now. i wanted to add some custom function now when i change on core modules or die dump delete nothing would happen my code still gets parsed

Answer (score 1):

1. Please confirm with cache clearing.
2. Do not forget to disable a cache in magento until you development process.

Comment: i did it everything clearing database to cache but non of them works at last except app and skin folder i had to replace all other folders from the fresh magento it did me a trick.